# Can't open the file upload to the FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

Im trying to upload a excel file on my ftp server. I can upload but uploaded file cant be open.I tried upload photo too. Same problem.
And files seems "0 byte" on ftp..

Here's my codes;

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://labquiz.hostoi.com/public_html/dosyalar/" + openFileDialog.SafeFileName);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("a3026029", "*******");
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(openFileDialog.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog.FileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        stream.Close();
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        MessageBox.Show("Upload File Complete, Status: " + response.StatusDescription);
        response.Close();
```

Comment: Consider using some more modern replacement for the `ftp` protocol. It is a leftover from the 70th, a nightmare for all network admins and does not offer any means of encryption. Consider using `sftp` or `scp` instead or at least `ftps`.

Comment: You read the data into the buffer, but I can't see any code to send the content of the buffer in the FTP request. Also, you are ignoring the return value from the `Stream.Read` method, so you don't know if the buffer is completely filled with data, or only partically.

Comment: I didnt understand u guys, my english is little. So what should I add the codes ? or what should I edit